# Nodejs nested query, response come only from last table starting table data show null value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

```
var connection = require('./../config');
var request = require("request");
module.exports.travelsummary = function (req, res, callback) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var start_date = req.body.start_date;
    var end_date = req.body.end_date;
    var full_data = [];
    if (id == undefined) {
        res.json({
            message: 'Please enter user id'
        });
        return;
    }
    var query1 = `SELECT imei FROM gs_user_objects WHERE user_id = ${id}`;
    connection.query(query1, function (error, result1, fields) {
        if (!error) {
            for (i = 0; i < result1.length; i++) {
                var table_name = 'gs_object_data_' + result1[i].imei;
                console.log(table_name);
                var query2 = `SELECT * FROM ${table_name} WHERE dt_server BETWEEN '${start_date}' AND '${end_date}'`;
                //var qry3 = `SELECT * FROM gs_object_data_358899059206311 WHERE dt_server BETWEEN '2019-05-27 06:06:57' AND '2019-05-28 06:06:57'`
                connection.query(query2, function (error, result2) {
                    full_data[i] = (result2);
                    console.log(full_data);
                    console.log(query2)
                    if (i == result1.length && !error && result2.length > 0) {
                        res.json({
                            message: 'data fetch successfuly',
                            data: full_data
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
};
```

from first query response take as a input in inner query then result sent in response but data get only last table.

how can i get every table data in separated array?

OUTPUT-

```
{
    "message": "data fetch successfully",
    "data": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        [
            {
                "dt_server": "2019-05-27T00:42:16.000Z",
                "dt_tracker": "2019-05-27T00:42:16.000Z",
                "lat": 18.601397,
                "lng": 73.932204,
                "altitude": 0,
                "angle": 0,
                "speed": 0,
                "params": "{\"gpslev\":\"5\",\"pump\":\"1\",\"track\":\"1\",\"bats\":\"1\",\"acc\":\"0\",\"defense\":\"0\",\"batl\":\"6\"}",
                "ignition": "",
                "power": "",
                "AC": "",
                "distance": "",
                "total_distance": ""
            },
            {
                "dt_server": "2019-05-27T00:49:46.000Z",
                "dt_tracker": "2019-05-27T00:49:46.000Z",
                "lat": 18.601397,
                "lng": 73.932204,
                "altitude": 0,
                "angle": 0,
                "speed": 0,
                "params": "{\"gpslev\":\"5\",\"pump\":\"1\",\"track\":\"1\",\"bats\":\"1\",\"acc\":\"0\",\"defense\":\"0\",\"batl\":\"6\"}",
                "ignition": "",
                "power": "",
                "AC": "",
                "distance": "",
                "total_distance": ""
            },
            {
                "dt_server": "2019-05-27T01:08:03.000Z",
                "dt_tracker": "2019-05-27T01:08:03.000Z",
                "lat": 18.601397,
                "lng": 73.932204,
                "altitude": 0,
                "angle": 0,
                "speed": 0,
                "params": "{\"gpslev\":\"5\",\"pump\":\"1\",\"track\":\"1\",\"bats\":\"1\",\"acc\":\"0\",\"defense\":\"0\",\"batl\":\"6\"}",
                "ignition": "",
                "power": "",
                "AC": "",
                "distance": "",
                "total_distance": ""
            },
            {
                "dt_server": "2019-05-27T01:17:50.000Z",
                "dt_tracker": "2019-05-27T01:17:50.000Z",
                "lat": 18.601397,
                "lng": 73.932204,
                "altitude": 0,
                "angle": 0,
                "speed": 0,
                "params": "{\"gpslev\":\"5\",\"pump\":\"1\",\"track\":\"1\",\"bats\":\"1\",\"acc\":\"0\",\"defense\":\"0\",\"batl\":\"6\"}",
                "ignition": "",
                "power": "",
                "AC": "",
                "distance": "",
                "total_distance": ""
            },
            {
                "dt_server": "2019-05-27T01:25:11.000Z",
                "dt_tracker": "2019-05-27T01:25:11.000Z",
                "lat": 18.601397,
                "lng": 73.932204,
                "altitude": 0,
                "angle": 0,
                "speed": 0,
                "params": "{\"gpslev\":\"5\",\"pump\":\"1\",\"track\":\"1\",\"bats\":\"1\",\"acc\":\"0\",\"defense\":\"0\",\"batl\":\"6\"}",
                "ignition": "",
                "power": "",
                "AC": "",
                "distance": "",
                "total_distance": ""
            },
            {
                "dt_server": "2019-05-27T01:32:31.000Z",
                "dt_tracker": "2019-05-27T01:32:31.000Z",
                "lat": 18.601397,
                "lng": 73.932204,
                "altitude": 0,
                "angle": 0,
                "speed": 0,
                "params": "{\"gpslev\":\"5\",\"pump\":\"1\",\"track\":\"1\",\"bats\":\"1\",\"acc\":\"0\",\"defense\":\"0\",\"batl\":\"6\"}",
                "ignition": "",
                "power": "",
                "AC": "",
                "distance": "",
                "total_distance": ""
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to search data from table that table get from first query then search data from every table that give first query so that why use nested query. 
In output push all data as null and last table data send in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Response from your db for the last query/table is being received before the response of previous queries.
Its better to use promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you need to use async-await or promise

Eg: Code,

```
   var connection = require('./../config');
var request = require("request");
module.exports.travelsummary = async function (req, res, callback) {
    try {
        var id = req.body.id;
        var start_date = req.body.start_date;
        var end_date = req.body.end_date;
        var full_data = [];
        if (id == undefined) {
            res.json({
                message: 'Please enter user id'
            });
            return;
        }
        let query1 = `SELECT imei FROM gs_user_objects WHERE user_id = ${id}`;
        let result1 = await connection.query(query1);
        if (result1 && result1.length) {
            await Promise.all(result1.map((item, i) => {
                let table_name = 'gs_object_data_' + item.imei;
                let query2 = `SELECT * FROM ${table_name} WHERE dt_server BETWEEN '${start_date}' AND '${end_date}'`;
                let result2 = await connection.query(query2);
                full_data.push(result2);
            }))
            res.json({
                message: 'data fetch successfuly',
                data: full_data
            })
        } else
            return "empty"

    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
};
```

In order to use async-await, you need to use promise-MySQL npm to create the connection. It is just a wrapper.

Comment: now error occur "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: did you modify module.exports.travelsummary = async function (req, res, callback) ?